# Unreal Engine Random Crashing on arch Linux Unhandled Exception: SIGABRT

Tags: linux, archlinux, unreal-engine4

I am running arch with an Nvidia graphics card

Around every six minutes Unreal Engine will randomly close and give me a bunch of warning and errors in the log
Here is the UE4.Log

```
[2017.05.19-00.47.14:159][579]LogLinux: === Critical error: ===
Unhandled Exception: SIGABRT: abort() called

[2017.05.19-00.47.14:159][579]LogLinux: Fatal error!

[Callstack]  00  0x00007f2d9cc8fdaf  FLinuxPlatformStackWalk::CaptureStackBackTrace(unsigned long long*, unsigned int, void*)
[Callstack]  01  0x00007f2d9cb71f86  FGenericPlatformStackWalk::StackWalkAndDump(char*, unsigned long, int, void*)
[Callstack]  02  0x00007f2d9cc509c2  FLinuxCrashContext::CaptureStackTrace()
[Callstack]  03  0x00007f2d92d3e1f0  CommonLinuxCrashHandler(FGenericCrashContext const&)
[Callstack]  04  0x00007f2d9cc55185  PlatformCrashHandler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
[Callstack]  05  0x00007f2da297efe0  /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x11fe0) [0x7f2da297efe0]
[Callstack]  06  0x00007f2d9211ea10  /usr/lib/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x110) [0x7f2d9211ea10]
[Callstack]  07  0x00007f2d9212013a  /usr/lib/libc.so.6(abort+0x17a) [0x7f2d9212013a]
[Callstack]  08  0x00007f2d9215d2b0  /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x722b0) [0x7f2d9215d2b0]
[Callstack]  09  0x00007f2d9216390e  /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7890e) [0x7f2d9216390e]
[Callstack]  10  0x00007f2d9216411e  /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7911e) [0x7f2d9216411e]
[Callstack]  11  0x00007f2d75722287  FOpenGLRHIState::CleanupResources()
[Callstack]  12  0x00007f2d7571d58c  FOpenGLDynamicRHI::Cleanup()
[Callstack]  13  0x00007f2d7571d370  FOpenGLDynamicRHI::Shutdown()
[Callstack]  14  0x00007f2d96c00fe2  RHIExit()
[Callstack]  15  0x0000000000424fcc  FEngineLoop::Exit() [/home/jayden/newU/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Launch/Private/LaunchEngineLoop.cpp, line 319]
[Callstack]  16  0x0000000000425492  GuardedMain(wchar_t const*) [/home/jayden/newU/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Launch/Private/Launch.cpp, line 178]
[Callstack]  17  0x00007f2d92d3f0b6  CommonLinuxMain(int, char**, int (*)(wchar_t const*))
[Callstack]  18  0x00007f2d9210b511  /usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1) [0x7f2d9210b511]
[Callstack]  19  0x00000000004153ba  ./UE4Editor(_start+0x2a) [0x4153ba]
The Full log is here
https://pastebin.com/PuKxNSXK
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks =)

Comment: Could be a Garbage Collection issue, it's one of the few shstems (that I know of) that run in the editor on a frequent interval. Not really familiar with Linux but the error happening in libpthread.so seems to be the cause. Which unreal version is this?

Comment: It is 4.15.2, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard procedure for this : 
Reboot Your Computer (Then try again)

Google it!

If you can use other projects without any problem, then you did something with the project, in which case you should tell me the procedure of making the project.

IF EVERYTHING FAILS...

Reinstall Unreal Engine

Try another operating system.